# Update feature does not update post but creates a new post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been creating a system where I create these entries but the problem is when I tried to create the edit feature, it does not update the post but creates a new one.

My controller file looks like this:

```
class BetsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @bet = Bet.new
  end

  def create
    @bets = Bet.new(bet_params)

    if @bets.save
        flash[:success] = 'Bet Successfull Logged.'
        redirect_to new_bet_path
      else
        flash[:danger] = 'Error, Bet has not been logged. Try again mate.'
        redirect_to new_bet_path
      end
  end

  def show
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @bet = Bet.find(params[:id])

        if @bet.update_attributes(bet_params)
            flash[:success] = "Bet Updated!"
            redirect_to bet_path(params[:id])
        else
            render action: :edit
        end
  end

  private

    def bet_params
      params.require(:bet).permit(:bet_placed, :game, :units_placed, :odds, :profit_or_loss)
    end

end
```

And also the form that is submitting looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :bet, url: bets_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :bet_placed %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bet_placed, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :game %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :game, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :units_placed %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :units_placed, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :odds %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :odds, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profit_or_loss %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :profit_or_loss, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit 'Update Profile', class: 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the rails natural routing the path `bets_path` always goes to the create method. As update needs an id, and you are not giving it,  it goes to create.

Change the form to,

```html
<%=  form_for @bet, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :bet_placed %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bet_placed, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  ....................

  <p class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :profit_or_loss %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :profit_or_loss, class: 'form-control' %>
  </p>

  <%= f.submit 'Update Profile', class: 'btn btn-default' %>

<% end %>
```

For reference,

```js
HTTPVerb    Path     controller#Action Named Helper
GET         /bets    bets#index        bets_path
GET        /bets/new    bets#new        new_bet_path
POST    /bets        bets#create       bets_path
GET        /bets/:id    bets#show         bet_path(:id)
GET       /bets/:id/edit   bets#edit     edit_bet_path(:id)
PATCH/PUT  /bets/:id    bets#update         bet_path(:id)
DELETE    /bets/:id    bets#destroy     bet_path(:id)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your form is currently setup, it will always hit the `create` action. If you change your `form_for` to the following it should work

```
<%= form_for @bet do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

You shouldn't need `multipart => true` either since your form doesn't have any file inputs.